# SQL join, 3x itself?

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have a table in my database called characters.  It tracks a character ID, name, marriedto, and fathersID.   "marriedto" is the Character ID of a character they are wed to, and "fathersID" is the character ID of that character's father.

I'd like to do a join statement in SQL that will pull all three names.
So my table might look like this:

```
CharID CharName marriedto fatherID
1      Jeremy   2         3
2      Sarah    1         4
3      Charles  5         6
```

I want to run a query to return something along these lines

```
Jeremy, Sarah, Charles
```

I can get one join on itself to happen, if I want it to give me just two names, but three is escaping me.

This works for two..

```
"SELECT C1.name AS spouse1, C2.name AS spouse2 
        FROM characters AS C1 
            JOIN characters AS C2 
                ON C1.marriedto= C2.characters_ID";
```

And I have attempted this for three, but it does not work.

```
"SELECT C1.name AS spouse1, C2.name AS spouse2 C3.name AS father
        FROM characters AS C1 
            JOIN characters AS C2 
                ON C1.marriedto= C2.characters_ID
            LEFT JOIN characters AS C3
                ON C1.fathersID = C3.characters_ID"
```

How can I do this triple join of just 1 table?

Comment: What about your query that you've tried doesn't work? Are you receiving an error message? Your triple join query sample has at least one syntax error that I can see - a missing comma after "AS spouse2". Also, the query doesn't match your data model column names, but that may not or may not be a part of your issues

Comment: This looks like an odd WHERE condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query looks fine.. I can see only a comma missing between `spouse2` and `C3.name`.

Comment: geez, always something simple.  Thanks!